# Vega and Gamma signs

Tags: options, option-pricing, gamma, vega

Do vega and gamma always have the same sign (ie both positive or both negative)? Under what circumstances can they have opposite signs?

Comment: For a long option position they are both positive and for a short option position they are both negative. ("option" = vanilla call or vanilla put). So yes, they always have the same sign.

Comment: In Black Scholes Model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually vega and gamma go in the same direction, but you can have opposite exposure in a calendar spread.

For an ATM option, vega decreases closer to maturity while gamma increases. If you implement the following:

-long a 1 month ATM option

-short a 2 months ATM option

you should be long gamma and short vega.

Comment: By the way that's called a "short ATM Calendar Spread".

Answer (score 3):

In the Black Scholes model, for an European option, we have 
$$\text{Vega}=Ke^{-r\tau}\phi(d_2)\sqrt{\tau}$$
and
$$\Gamma=Ke^{-r\tau}\phi(d_2)\frac{1}{S^2\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}$$
thus
$$\frac{\text{Vega}}{\Gamma}=S^2\sigma{\tau}>0$$

Comment: Note that this is true for single European vanilla options. It no longer holds for portfolios of options. Even when the volatility surface is flat, you can build a portfolio of options with different maturities to obtain gamma and vega positions of opposite signs. Similarly, when the volatility smile of a maturity is not flat, you can achieve the same with a position in different strikes of that maturity.